# A burrito is a Mexican food or dish?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, food

Can I say a burrito is a Mexican food ? Or should I use dish instead ?

Can you say

> a Mexican food

Comment: Can you say *Go get a food out of the fridge?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Food is an uncountable noun. Sticking *Mexican* in front of it does make it countable. To sum up: *Mexican food* is uncountable.

*Dish* is countable. Therefore *Mexican dish* is countable.

You do not use the indefinite article before uncountable nouns.

Note: I would not call a burrito a Mexican dish, as it is not a meal. I would call it Mexican food, or a type of Mexican food. To be more specific, it is probably *Texmex food*, which is food eaten in the southwestern United States that is roughly based on Mexican food, but is not like Mexican food found in the interior of Mexico.

Answer (score 1):

Both.

It is food (obviously).

As for [***dish***](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/dish), it depends:

> 1a) any container, generally shallow and concave and of porcelain, earthenware, glass, plastic, etc. for serving or holding food
>   1b) ([pl.]) plates, bowls, saucers, cups, etc., collectively
>
> 2a) the food in a dish
>   2b) a particular kind of food, or food prepared in a certain way   ⇒ "one's favorite dish"

So I would not call it a "dish" if served in a paper wrapper, but in a restaurant on a plate it could be. This might also have some special preparation with other food or condiments on the side, in which case the combination of items could be referred to as a "dish".

As for article use, it depends on context but I think you would likely say "Mexican food" instead of "a Mexican food", and "a Mexican dish".